# How the double recursion works in C/C++ - for example depth of a binary tree?

Tags: c++, c, recursion

Recursion doesn't strike naturally to me. A few programs, which I could understand was Factorial, where factorial of n is n * factorial(n-1). Similarly, fibonacci series - Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2. Also, a bst- insert, search. All these recursion functions have one thing common -  a condition to return the concrete value. Otherwise, it will call itself with a different parameter. Once the concrete value is returned, all the calls are unfolded. However, I am not able to understand the programs where the recursion is one after the other. What happens over there. How can I think on those lines naturally? For example - here is the program -

What is the significance of the following lines?

```
 /* compute the depth of each subtree */
           int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left);
           int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right);



int maxDepth(struct node* node)
{
   if (node==NULL)
       return 0;
   else
   {
       /* compute the depth of each subtree */
       int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left);
       int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right);

       /* use the larger one */
       if (lDepth > rDepth)
           return(lDepth+1);
       else return(rDepth+1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Think of the [call tree](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cburch/survey/recurse/hanoiex.html)

Comment: The recursion is where you call `maxDepth` inside `maxDepth`. Actually, I did not get your question with the significance.

Comment: Not much different with fibonacci, you mentioned - just two recursive calls on each level.

Answer (score 3):

While searching the tree, the condition that returns a concrete value is `if (node==NULL)` and the concrete value returned is `0`, which is a tree of depth `0`. Consider the following tree ([from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree))

[image]

Starting at node 8, the code will recurse to node 3, and then to node 1. When it tries to recurse to the left child of node 1, it will find `NULL` and return 0. Then it will try the right child of node 1, which will also return 0. At this point node 1 comes to the `if` statement

```
   if (lDepth > rDepth)
       return(lDepth+1);
   else return(rDepth+1);
```

Since both `lDepth` and `rDepth` are `0`, node 1 returns `1` to node 3. Then node 3 recurses to node 6, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `maxDepth(node->left)` will result in an immediate call to `maxDepth(node->left)`, until there it nothing left (no pun intended) on the left most side of the tree.  Then the last call returns and there will be a call to `maxDepth(node->right)`.

This is a so-called 'depth-first' traversal, in that we go as far up the tree as possible and then visit the leaves on each branch until we're done on the branch and then we back-up to the fork.

Perhaps the best way to understand this code is to draw a picture of a small binary tree, and step through the code to see what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Mentally, it may help to separate the logic into two parts.  If you have a pointer possibly to a node in a singly-linked list, and define the depth of a NULL pointer as being 0, then you can say the depth of any other node is one more than the depth of the node to which it links.

```
    {node3 p_next_->}---->{node2 p_next_->}---->{node1 p_next_=nullptr}
```

So, the code for this would be:

```
int depth(Node* p)
{
     if (p == NULL) return 0;
     return depth(p->p_next_) + 1;
}
```

Then, your question is about a binary tree... the logic is similar but each time you work out the depth of a node, you're saying "well, this node may have a right and/or a left hierarchy of nodes under it... my depth is one more than the greater of their depths".

---

Alternatively, it might help to think of a family, say fred has two children sue and max, and so on....

```
          fred
          /  \
        sue  max
       /  \
    sally charlie
             /
           june
```

Here, working out the depth of say sue is a bit like asking "is she a child (depth 1), a parent (depth 2), a grandparent (depth 3), a great-grandparent (depth 4)?"

We can see she's sally's mother (depth 2 on that side), but she's june's grandmother (depth 3) on that side.

We can *work out* that answer of 3 systematically by saying sue's depth is one more than the deepest of sally and charlie's, and sally's got no kids (their imaginary depth is 0) so she's depth 1 so sue'2 at least 2, but charlie's one more than june who's one more than her imaginarykids (depth 0) i.e. june's 1 so charlie's 2 so sue's actually 3, being more than the count from sally's side.